# GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException: Connection refused for URI errors When Setting Up Local Development Environment

Tags: drupal, guzzle

I'm encountering multiple connection refused errors while attempting to configure a local development environment for the website on my Windows desktop. The website application is based on Drupal 10, and there are some modules designed to fetch data from various external URLs, I am getting the following error

```
GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException: Connection refused for URI https://auth.mywebsite.io/connect/token
```

This is happening for multiple URLs. Interestingly, these URLs are accessible via web browsers, indicating they are not blocked at the network level. However, attempts to ping these URLs from the command line result in unsuccessful responses.

Comment: How is your environment setup? Are you running php locally? Or, using a container?

Answer (score 0):

There could be a lot of probable causes, however one important thing to check would be if you are behind a proxy.

If yes, you'll need to route your requests through the proxy

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the verbose flag in your curl call to help in debugging?

e.g. curl-v https://auth.mywebsite.io/connect/token